# React Functional Component with useState Hook Breaks Component Library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm creating a library of custom react components and I'm running into an issue that I think must be related to how my package is getting created.  When I add a functional component that utilizes the 'useState' hook to my library and import it as a dependency in another project, I'm getting the "Invalid Hook Call".  I've checked the three possible scenarios given in the error that could be causing the error and eliminated all of them.  When I copy the offending component to my main project directory and import it directly (rather than through my custom react components package) it works as expected, so I'm clearly doing something wrong when I create my package, I just can't determine what.

My webpack.config.js file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: ['react', 'react-dom'],
};
```

My bable.rc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "useESModules": true,
        "regenerator": false
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements"
  ]
}
```

My package.json file:

```
{...
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "webpack",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js",
    "stylelint": "stylelint **/*.*css --ip **/*.min.css -s scss"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^11.0.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^11.0.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^11.0.0-beta.2",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-react-important-stuff": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "semantic-release": "^17.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.8.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
    "tinycolor2": "^1.4.2",
    "webpack": "^5.5.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-color": "^2.19.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting this error using npm link?

Comment: Yes, I'm using npm link to test my package locally.

Comment: Here at the end you will find how to fixed, https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: That did it.  It's a little wonky, but it works.  So I'm using npm link in my project to point it toward the local version of one of the project's dependencies, but I'm also using npm link to point the local dependency toward my project's node_modules/react folder.

Comment: And this is not only for local packages. I'm having the same issue with a dependency. So what I had to do was `npm link` at `node_modules/<package>/node_modules/react` and then `npm link "react"` at my project's root folder. Just... terrible.

Comment: Just for ref - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991. Hooks won't work when there are version mismatches of react / react dom

Comment: Just for ref - github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991. Hooks won't work when there are version mismatches of react / react dom